# Is explicit call of insertSections:withRowAnimation: necessary?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` showing photos and albums on the phone. When the app is started if there are no photos on the phone, I have zero sections. Then during runtime I take a photo with the app and in this moment I want to show the album.

My `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method returns 0 if there are no photos, and 1 if there is at least one. In this moment when the new photo is taken do I have to call `insertSections:withRowAnimation:` or is it enough just to return 1 in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a new photo,you just change the model of your tableview.You have to call something to let your view update.

So,you need to `insertSections:withRowAnimation:`,or call `reloadData`.So that `numberOfSectionsInTableView` will be called and return 1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have to call `insertSections:withRowAnimation:` (or `reloadData`). If you don't then the refresh of the table view is not triggered, i.e. the delegate call `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` is not even invoked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have elements to display in your tableview, you should at least return 1 in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`

You also have to use [`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:) to set how many rows you want to have in your section(s)